# Vertices, Edges and Line Segment intersection points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, graph-theory

So, I have a bunch of graph edges defined by start and end vertices

```
i.e. edge = (startVertex, EndVertex).
```

No coordinates i.e x or y points provided.
How do I find the corresponding line segments and then discover if the resulting segments intersect or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Abstractly, it doesn't make sense to ask about which edges interesect, or even to ask if any of them do intersect.  You can really only ask this for a geometric realization of the graph, such as a drawing in the plane, or three space.  But for an abstract ( finite ) graph, you can always embed it in threespace with no interesections.  it's not always possible to embed a graph in the plane with no intersections, but it is always possible to avoid interesecting any given pair of edges, so even if you know the graph is embedded in the plane, without knowing something about the embedding you can't say if two edges intersect.